# Access Hive Tables in SQLClient but not from the Putty

Tags: sql, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, putty

I am new to Hive, MapReduce and Hadoop.
I am using Putty to connect to hive table and access records in the tables. So what I did is- I opened Putty and in the host name I typed- `vip.name.com` and then I click `Open`. And then I entered my username and password and then few commands to get to Hive sql. Below is the list what I did

```
$ bash
bash-3.00$ hive
Hive history file=/tmp/rkost/hive_job_log_rkost_201207010451_1212680168.txt
hive> set mapred.job.queue.name=mdhi-technology;
hive> select * from table LIMIT 1;
```

So my question is-

**Is there any other way I can do the same thing in any Sql client like Sql Developer or Squirel SQL Client instead of doing it from the command prompt. And if it is there then what is the step by step process to do this considering my example as I am logging to `vip.name.com` from Putty .**

And same thing if I need to do through JDBC Program in my windows machine then how I can do it. Means with the JDBC Program, how I can access Hive tables and get the result back. As I know how I can do this with the oracle tables. But the only confusion I have is, as I am using this hostname `vip.name.com` to log into Putty. I am hoping the question is clear. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

**In short my question is- Can I do the same thing in any SQLClient instead of logging from the Putty?**

Update-

I tried doing the way Mark has suggested me. But I am always getting- `Hive: Could not establish connection to vip.host.com:10000/default: java.net.ConnectionException: Connection timed out: connect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you doing with Putty is SSH'ing into a machine with Hive installed and set up. Then you are issuing Hive queries from the Hive command line. That is one way of issuing Hive queries. There are other ways that don't require SSH'ing, one you probably need is connection via JDBC.

[Here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_Hive.html#HiveJDBCDriver) is an article which describes how to connect to a Hive installation on Amazon's EMR cluster using SQuirreL via JDBC. The article might appear to be Amazon specific but it's not. As long you have Hive server running on one of the nodes of the cluster and no firewall impeding connection between the client machine and one running Hive, you should be able to connect.

A couple things you might want to keep in mind related to the above link:

- You can ignore step 3 where it asks you to create a SSH tunnel unless you are using EMR.
- The port that you enter in your connection URI might be different in your case. Replace localhost with the fully qualified domain name of the machine that Hive is running on. To find out which port Hive server is listening on, you can look into your Hive server nanny log file present in the log directory (whose location depends on your installation) or run a simple `netstat -a` command. I believe 10000 is the default port number, so it might make sense to try out 10000 directly.

Comment: Yes, instead of localhost, use the fully qualified domain name (ares-ingest.vip.host.com). For your port, can you please try 10000?