# How to know Hive and Hadoop versions from command prompt?

Tags: hadoop, hive

How can I find which Hive version I am using from the command prompt. Below is the details-

I am using Putty to connect to hive table and access records in the tables. So what I did is- I opened Putty and in the host name I typed- `leo-ingesting.vip.name.com` and then I click `Open`. And then I entered my username and password and then few commands to get to Hive sql. Below is the list what I did

```
$ bash
bash-3.00$ hive
Hive history file=/tmp/rkost/hive_job_log_rkost_201207010451_1212680168.txt
hive> set mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology;
hive> select * from table LIMIT 1;
```

So is there any way from the command prompt I can find which hive version I am using and Hadoop version too?

Comment: Can I make a request that *every* single CLI in the world start supporting -v, --v, -version, and --version as aliases for each other so we can all just get on with our lives.

Comment: you can't: gnu getopt would consider -version as -v -e -r -s -i -o -n, for example. Also, proper CLI uses -v as alias for --verbose.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can not get hive version from command line.

You can checkout hadoop version as mentioned by Dave.

Also if you are using cloudera distribution, then look directly at the libs:

ls /usr/lib/hive/lib/ and check for hive library

```
hive-hwi-0.7.1-cdh3u3.jar
```

You can also check the compatible versions here:

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh5/v5-1-x/CDH-Version-and-Packaging-Information/CDH-Version-and-Packaging-Information.html

Comment: Are you sure the path is `/usr/lib/hive/lib/` ?

Comment: @RaihanJamal: Yes if you are using cloudera distribution. :)

Comment: Ok. got it. `hive-0.6 I have`. I am asking this question since I am trying to Access Hive metadata using SQL Client. But somehow I am not able to do it. I posted the question here. Can you please take a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278040/access-hive-tables-in-sqlclient-but‌​-not-from-the-putty. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: yes you can get it from commande line : hive -e "set hive.hwi.war.file;" |grep hwi| cut -d'-' -f3

Comment: I am getting "hive.hwi.war.file is undefined"

Comment: @pyfunc  What about HDP?

Comment: hive --version shows the version.

`[root@mysupercomputer ~]# hive --version`
`Hive 1.2.1`
`Subversion git://localhost.localdomain/home/sush/dev/hive.git -r 243e7c1ac39cb7ac8b65c5bc6988f5cc3162f558`
`Compiled by sush on Fri Jun 19 02:03:48 PDT 2015 From source with checksum ab480aca41b24a9c3751b8c023338231`

Answer (score 159):

```
$ hive --version
Hive version 0.8.1.3
```

EDIT: added another '-' before the version. Doesn't work for newer versions. Hope it works for all now.

Known to work in the following distributions:

- HortonWorks distribution: `$ hive --version Hive 0.14.0.2.2.0.0-2041`
- CDH 5.3

It does not work:

- CDH 4.3
- HDinsight (Azure)

Comment: I have no idea why someone downvoted this, but it works for me.  Maybe it is specific to Amazon Elastic MapReduce (EMR), or to the Hive version.

Comment: I have cloudera 5.11. Worked fine for me

Comment: CDH 5.15, worked for me. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ... Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.15.2   I don't know why this answer is on the second, not first position

Answer (score 48):

```
$ hadoop version
Hadoop 0.20.2-cdh3u4
```

Not sure you can get the Hive version from the command line, though. Maybe you could use something like the `hive.hwi.war.file` property or pull it out of the classpath, though.

Comment: Thanks Dave, It worked. I am asking this question since I am trying to Access Hive metadata using SQL Client. But somehow I am not able to do it. I posted the question here. Can you please take a look into this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278040/access-hive-tables-in-sqlclient-but-not-from-the-putty`. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @RaihanJamal I have no idea; I've never tried using anything like that with Hive.

Answer (score 25):

You CAN get version from command line(hive or beeline).

```
hive> select version();
OK
1.1.0-cdh5.12.0 rUnknown
Time taken: 2.815 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive>
```

Comment: I got FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Line 1:7 Invalid function 'version'

Comment: @Ganesh Chances are your hive version is not sufficiently recent. Check out https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12983

Answer (score 15):

The below works on Hadoop 2.7.2

```
hive --version

hadoop version

pig --version

sqoop version

oozie version
```

Answer (score 14):

This should certainly work:

```
hive --version
```

Answer (score 13):

```
hive -e "set hive.hwi.war.file;" | cut -d'-' -f3
```

Answer (score 12):

Use the version flag from the CLI

```
[hadoop@usernode~]$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.7.3-amzn-1
Subversion git@aws157git.com:/pkg/Aws157BigTop -r d94115f47e58e29d8113a887a1f5c9960c61ab83
Compiled by ec2-user on 2017-01-31T19:18Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 1833aada17b94cfb94ad40ccd02d3df8
This command was run using /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.7.3-amzn-1.jar


[hadoop@usernode ~]$ hive --version
Hive 1.0.0-amzn-8
Subversion git://ip-20-69-181-31/workspace/workspace/bigtop.release-rpm-4.8.4/build/hive/rpm/BUILD/apache-hive-1.0.0-amzn-8-src -r d94115f47e58e29d8113a887a1f5c9960c61ab83
Compiled by ec2-user on Tue Jan 31 19:51:34 UTC 2017
From source with checksum 298304aab1c4240a868146213f9ce15f
```

Answer (score 9):

From the hive shell issue 'set system.sun.java.command'
The hive-cli.jar version is the hive version.

```
<code>
hive> set system:sun.java.command;
system:sun.java.command=org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.2-1.cdh4.2.2.p0.10/bin/../lib/hive/lib/hive-cli-**0.10.0**-cdh**4.2.2**.jar org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver
hive> 
</code>
```

The above example shows Hive version 0.10.0 for CDH version 4.2.2

Comment: Jai can you tell what it does !!

Comment: system.sun.java.command will be already set by hive and it does nothing. Its one way to find out the hive version.

Answer (score 8):

```
hive --version

hadoop version
```

Answer (score 7):

We can find hive version by

- on linux shell : "hive --version"
- on hive shell  : " ! hive --version;"

above cmds works on hive 0.13 and above.

Set system:sun.java.command; 
gives the hive version from hue hive editor it gives the the jar name which includes the version.

Answer (score 6):

to identify hive version on a EC2 instance use

```
hive --version
```

Answer (score 5):

Below command works , i tried this and got the current version as

```
/usr/bin/hive --version
```

Comment: Hi Shikhar , which Hadoop version are you trying this worked for me on cloudera CDH 5

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `beeline` to connect to hive, then `!dbinfo` will give all the underlying database details and in the output `getDatabaseProductVersion` will have the hive database version.

Sample output:
`getDatabaseProductVersion   1.2.1000.2.4.3.0-227`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using hortonworks distro then using CLI you can get the version with the command:

```
hive --version
```

[image: Example output]

Answer (score 2):

We can also get the version by looking at the version of the hive-metastore jar file.

For example:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/hive/lib/ | grep metastore
hive-metastore-0.13.1.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get Hive version

```
hive --version
```

if you want to know hive version and its related package versions.

```
rpm -qa|grep hive
```

Output will be like below.

```
libarchive2-2.5.5-5.19
hive-0.13.0.2.1.2.2-516
perl-Archive-Zip-1.24-2.7
hive-jdbc-0.13.0.2.1.2.2-516
webhcat-tar-hive-0.13.0.2.1.2.2_516-2
hive-webhcat-0.13.0.2.1.2.2-516
hive-hcatalog-0.13.0.2.1.2.2-516
```

Latter gives better understanding of hive and its dependents.  Nevertheless rpm needs to be present.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below command to get hive version

**hive --service version**

Answer (score 2):

From your SSH connection to edge node, you can simply type

```
hive --version

Hive 1.2.1000.x.x.x.x-xx
```

This returns the Hive version for your distribution of Hadoop. Another approach is if you enter into `beeline`, you can find the version straight away.

```
beeline
Beeline version 1.2.1000.x.x.x.x-xx by Apache Hive
```

Answer (score 1):

another way is to make a REST call, if you have WebHCat (part of Hive project) installed, is

```
curl -i http://172.22.123.63:50111/templeton/v1/version/hive?user.name=foo
```

which will come back with JSON like

{"module":"hive","version":"1.2.1.2.3.0.0-2458"}

[WebHCat docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat+Reference+VersionHive)  has some details

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get version of your hive by using "hive command":

```
hive --service version
```

You can get a list of available service names by using following "hive command":

```
hive --service help
```

Answer (score 0):

you can look for the jar file as soon as you login to hive

```
jar:file:/opt/mapr/hive/hive-0.12/lib/hive-common-0.12-mapr-1401-140130.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

/usr/bin/hive --version worked for me.

```
[qa@ip-10-241-1-222 ~]$ /usr/bin/hive --version
Hive 0.13.1-cdh5.3.1
Subversion file:///data/1/jenkins/workspace/generic-package-rhel64-6-0/topdir/BUILD/hive-0.13.1-cdh5.3.1 -r Unknown
Compiled by jenkins on Tue Jan 27 16:38:55 PST 2015
From source with checksum 1bb86e4899928ce29cbcaec8cf43c9b6
[qa@ip-10-241-1-222 ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

On HDInsight I tried the hive --version, but it did not recognize the option or mention it in the help.

```
D:\Users\admin1>%hive_home%/bin/hive --version
Unrecognized option: --version
usage: hive
 -d,--define <key=value>          Variable subsitution to apply to hive
                                  commands. e.g. -d A=B or --define A=B
    --database <databasename>     Specify the database to use
 -e <quoted-query-string>         SQL from command line
 -f <filename>                    SQL from files
 -H,--help                        Print help information
 -h <hostname>                    connecting to Hive Server on remote host
    --hiveconf <property=value>   Use value for given property
    --hivevar <key=value>         Variable subsitution to apply to hive
                                  commands. e.g. --hivevar A=B
 -i <filename>                    Initialization SQL file
 -p <port>                        connecting to Hive Server on port number
 -S,--silent                      Silent mode in interactive shell
 -v,--verbose                     Verbose mode (echo executed SQL to the
                                  console)
```

However when you login to the head node and start the hive console it prints out some helpful configuration information from which the version can be read:

```
D:\Users\admin1>%hive_home%/bin/hive 
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/C:/apps/dist/hive-0.13.0.2.1.11.0-2316/conf/hive-log4j.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/apps/dist/hadoop-2.4.0.2.1.11.0-2316/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.j
ar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/apps/dist/hbase-0.98.0.2.1.11.0-2316-hadoop2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4
j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
hive> quit;
```

From this I would say I have Hive version 0.13 deployed, which is consistent with this list of versions https://hive.apache.org/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the version of installed Hadoop 3.0.3 by the following command
$HADOOP_HOME/bin$ ./hadoop version
                          which gave me the following output

Hadoop 3.0.3
Source code repository https://yjzhangal@git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 37fd7d752db73d984dc31e0cdfd590d252f5e075
Compiled by yzhang on 2018-05-31T17:12Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 736cdcefa911261ad56d2d120bf1fa
This command was run using  /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.0.3.jar