# Connect to Hive server using SquirrelSQL client

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, squirrel-sql

I am trying to connect **SquirrelSQL client** to **Hive**.

I am running Hadoop/Hive on a Debian 7.0 VM on virtualbox.

Hive server is online, and when I ping my vm with my laptop client, the vm is responding, it's OK.

Then, I trying to connect to Hive using SquirrelSQL.

I'm using **Amazon JDBC driver**, related to this post : [Access Hive Tables in SQLClient but not from the Putty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278040/access-hive-tables-in-sqlclient-but-not-from-the-putty)

The connection is ok, but, my unique table (pays) is not visible in the client (there is no tables at all !), and when I'm trying to select my unique by the simple query : `SELECT * FROM pays;` I'm getting this error :

```
Error: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
SQLState:  08S01
ErrorCode: 0
```

I was looking for an issue on the web, but I haven't found anything.

Thanks  for your help =)

ps: sorry for my poor english...

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions on link [Hive JDBC Interface](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveJDBCInterface#HiveJDBCInterface-IntegrationwithSQuirrelSQLClient) on section "Integration with SQuirrel SQL Client", Its working for me after import jar files to SQuirrel/lib folder..

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please add the relevant content from any links to the answer in future to ensure that the solution for perpetuity. thanks